# .Net Framework 4.5.1 RemoveAt

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, linq, entity-framework

I  have migrated my MVC application from linq-to-Sql to EF 6.1.1, and from .Net Framework 4.0 to 4.5.1.  I used the following to remove items from list:

```
 List<int> idsToKeep = new List<int>();
   for (int i = 0; i < visit.Client.Count; i++)
                {
                Client om = visit.Client[i];
                if (om.ClientId == 0)
                    continue;
                bool itemExists = false;
                foreach (int id in idsToKeep)
                    if (om.ClientId == id)
                        itemExists = true;
                if (!itemExists)
                    {
                    visit.Client.RemoveAt(i);
                    i--;
                    }
                }
                   return errors;
            }
```

Initially I got this error:

```
cannot apply indexing with to an expression of type system.collections.generic.iCollection
```

in this line:

```
  Client om = visit.Client[i];
```

Changed it to:

```
  Client om = visit.Client.ElementAt(i);
```

I am not sure this is correct, however did not get any error; the problem is I can not resolve RemoveAt in this line:

```
  visit.Client.RemoveAt(i);
```

Would appreciate your suggestions

Comment: You should not alter a collection that you are iterating.

Comment: Client is a `Collection` and not an `IList<T>`. There is no array, so there is no concept of an index position.

Comment: Please format your code

Comment: And you say this was working with .NET 4.0, with a `Client` of the exact same type? This can't be.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems `visit.Client` is an `ICollection<T>` and there is no `RemoveAt` method on `ICollection<T>`.You can try using `ToList` method to turn it into a List, or you can use linq to exclude items you want:

```
visit.Client = visit.Client.Where(x => x.ClientId == 0 ||
                                       idsToKeep.Contains(x.ClientId)).ToList();
```

Comment: Just two minor problems. It is `ClientId` and he wants to keep also the ClientId == 0

Comment: Thank you Selman, I am using this code to update a list after the user removes a line from a list.  So I was checking the new list and if any line is not in the form collection I remove it.  All lines are listed with the same id.  I am wondering why it worked before in the old application.  Thank you.

Comment: You are right, I checked the old designer, the relation between visit and client was one to many, while in emdx is one to one that is maybe the reason I got it as ICollection.  Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try this, the trick is you have to remove from bottom up...

```
        var visit = new Visit();
        List<int> idsToKeep = new List<int>();
        visit.Client.Reverse();
        foreach(var thing in visit.Client){
            Client om = thing;
            if (om.ClientId == 0)continue;
            bool itemExists = false;
            foreach (int id in idsToKeep)
                if (om.ClientId == id)
                    itemExists = true;
            if (!itemExists)
            {
                visit.Client.Remove(thing);
            }
        }
        return errors;
```